# Message Box sending Windows messages?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7

I've got a relatively simple Window class. I've created a window, associated my `this`, etc etc. Now later, I've thrown an exception to indicate a problem. When I call `MessageBox` to pop up the error, the program crashes, because it's attempting to call my Window Proc. Now, I mean, admittedly, I failed SRP here and just writing a brief self-owning HWND class will solve this problem, as the window wasn't cleaned up properly. However, I'm really mystified as to why it's trying to process Window messages in my `MessageBox` call- the owner parameter is `nullptr`. Any suggestions?

Edit: If I call `DestroyWindow` appropriately, then now the message box just doesn't show up, although the app doesn't crash. It only works if I manually remove `this` from the window, so that if the proc were called it would forward to `DefWindowProc`, and then `DestroyWindow`. I mean, I thought that if you called `MessageBox` without an owner, then it would just work, regardless of what you had done to other windows in the system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is happening here is that there are still messages for the dud window in the queue when you show the message box. The message box runs a modal window message pump and dispatches the troublesome messages. Remember that all windows created from the same thread share a single message queue.

I have no idea how to fix your problem but that's what's going on.

By the way, passing a null owner isn't a great idea as it will result in your message box not being minimised when your main app is minimised, for example.

Comment: It's only for termination or `printf` debugging anyway, so the poor behaviour isn't a concern.